# Pre-Allocation in Events and Bitmaps

Tags: android, garbage-collection, allocation

I'm writing a game for Android and I'm having noticeable pauses every few seconds when the GC runs. I've reduced the allocations to a minimum and the only remaining allocations (according to Allocation Tracker) are produced by `Bitmap.createBitmap(..)`, an `onTouchEvent` and an `onKeyEvent`. `Bitmap.createBitmap(..)` is called twice per Frame, and cannot be removed.

**Now to my question:** Is there an alternative way to read the events and another way to create bitmaps? Or a way to pre-allocate the memory needed for the operations and a way of telling them to use that?

**InputHandler class (contains listeners):**

```
public class InputHandler {

private ISwarmInput mGame;

// Declare input types
public static final int USE_TOUCH = 0;
public static final int USE_MOTION = 1;
public static final int USE_KEY = 2;
public static final int USE_TOUCH_AND_KEY = 3;

private int mInputType;
public OrientationEventListener mOrientationListener;
public OnTouchListener mTouchListener;
public OnKeyListener mKeyListener;

public InputHandler(Context context, ISwarmInput game) {
    mGame = game;
    mTouchListener = createTouchListener();
    mKeyListener = createKeyListener();
}

public OrientationEventListener createTiltListener(Context context) {
    return new OrientationEventListener(context) {
        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
            if (mInputType == USE_MOTION) {
                mGame.setAngle(orientation);
            }
        }
    };
}

public OnTouchListener createTouchListener() {
    return new OnTouchListener() {
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            if (mInputType == USE_TOUCH || mInputType == USE_TOUCH_AND_KEY) {
                if (readPointIn(event.getX(), event.getY())) {
                    mGame.addNewPoint((int) event.getX(),
                            (int) event.getY());
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    };
}

public OnKeyListener createKeyListener() {
    return new OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (mInputType == USE_KEY || mInputType == USE_TOUCH_AND_KEY) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                    mGame.setAngle(-90);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                    mGame.setAngle(180);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                    mGame.setAngle(90);
                    break;
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                    mGame.setAngle(0);
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
}
}
```

**Bitmap-creating part**

```
public void drawHead(Canvas canv) {
    mat.reset();
    nextFrame();

    setRotationAndFlip(mat);

    this.bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(SPRITESHEET, Bird.mCurFrame * BIG_W[mUseBird], 0,
            BIG_W[mUseBird], BIG_H[mUseBird], mat, true);
    super.drawPlaceable(canv);

    mat.preScale((float)0.6, (float)0.6);
    this.bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(SPRITESHEET, Bird.mCurFrame * BIG_W[mUseBird], 0,
            BIG_W[mUseBird], BIG_H[mUseBird], mat, true);
}
```

The game is something similar to snake, you're a bird and for each worm you eat you get a smaller bird fallowing you. The second bitmap is for the following, smaller bird.

Comment: Yes you need to pre-allocate and reuse both. If you want suggestions you might want to show your current implementation.

Comment: @mibollma: Done. So, how do I pre-allocate and reuse it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reusable input events you might want to take a look at this implementation: http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/source/browse/trunk/backends/gdx-backend-android/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidInput.java

Regarding bitmaps... maybe you should make some sprites the same size so you can reuse your bitmap.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll look through it. How will using sprites the same size help anything? The allocation (for a canvas, paint and bitmap) is taking place in the Bitmap.createBitmap(..) internal code.

Comment: You are right it won't help in your case. So i guess your alternatives are to create a bunch of different rotations like 5° steps or something or to use Canvas.rotate() (which is also slow).

Comment: I realized the events weren't the problem, couldn't solve the bitmaps though. Thanks for the help.